# Align widgets round a circle

Tags: flutter

I want to align a list of widgets round a circle, so the whole thing could appear circluar like this image [image]

is there any widgets i can use, or a list of widgets that are could go and read up on, that can help me to achieve something like this?.

Comment: you like to have theses 4 blocs(W,D,R,O) like the image? you try with `stack`, `Transform`

Comment: I tried to warp my stack in a container, and used a Positioned to position the widget in the stack, but my default position is outside my circle.

Comment: Can you include that code-snippet, including the output image you are getting, and what is wrong with it?

Comment: `Container( 
   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.1,
   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.1,
   margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
     color: Colors.red,
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(180)
  ),
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      // Text("sdf"),
      Positioned(
        child: Text("A"))
    ],
    )
)`

Answer (score 2):

Using `Aling` widget is simpler than `Positioned` widget. On `Positioned` widget it was having extra size beyond text, and it might be handled by providing `height` and `weight`.

```dart
class CCSh extends StatelessWidget {
  final double size;

  const CCSh({Key? key, required this.size}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      width: size,
      height: size,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.green,
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 4)),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment(1, 0),
            child: Text("D"),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment(0, -1),
            child: Text("W"),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment(-1, 0),
            child: Text("O"),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment(0, 1),
            child: Text("R"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

> It is having `Container` size, you need to calculate if the widget gets beyond radius.

More about [Align](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html)